# How to clear cell contents in VBA if they are within a range of numeric values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear the contents of any cells within a column that contain the numbers 1-12. I'm currently using a for loop and an if statement, going one at a time through the numbers 1-12 and clearing the contents if the cell contains those values. The file I'm working with has over 35,000 rows of data; is there a more efficient way to tell the macro to delete those numbers without creating an individual elseif statement for them?

```
For r = 2 To i
    If Cells(r, 1).Value = "1" Then
        Cells(r, 1).ClearContents
        ElseIf Cells(r, 1).Value = "2" Then
        Cells(r, 1).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use comparison operators combined with an And:

```
For r = 2 to i
    If Cells(r, 1).Value >= 1 And Cells(r, 1).Value <= 12 Then
        Cells(r, 1).ClearContents
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, ">=1", xlAnd, "<=12"
        .Offset(1).ClearContents
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```